# How can I identify a element of an unordered list (generated by a JSON object) individually?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

For some reason I can't understand I cannot retrieve the individual IDs of the unordered list `li` generated automatically through a `GET` request. 
I have noticed that it works when I manually add the `li` elements under the `ul` block. Like this:

```
<ul id="browse_list" style="list-style-type:none">
<li id="abc">Link 1</li>
<li id="def">Link 2</li>
</ul>
```

Current HTML:

```
<h2 id="browse_menu" style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> browse</h2>
<ul id="browse_list" style="list-style-type:none"></ul>
<h2 id="favorites_menu" style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> favorites</h2>
```

Current JS:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {"render": "json"},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: "https://opml.radiotime.com/Browse.ashx?",
    success: function (data, status) {
    //console.log(data, status);
    var cathegories = []
    $.each(data['body'], function (id, list) {
        cathegories.push('<li id="browse_' + list.key + '" style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + "&nbsp;" + list.text.toLowerCase() + '</li>');
    });
    console.log(cathegories);
    $("#browse_list").html(cathegories);
    },
    error: function (textStatus, errorMessage) {
        console.log(errorMessage);
    }
    });

    $("#browse_list li").click(function() {
      var data = (this).id;
    console.log(this.id);
  });
```

Thank you for any hint!

Comment: Your click event handler binding is outside of the ajax call, which is asynchronous.  It needs to be moved into your success callback

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!